# SQLite query not working - (Objective-c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm using xCode 4.3.2. Here I'm trying to load Column Names and Values from the database. When i use sqlQuery: "select * from mytable Where company like 'SONY'", its not working, but "select * from mytable" is woking fine. Could you please help me?

```
static int loadCallback(void *context, int count, char **values, char **columns)
{
    NSString *columnName;
    NSString *columnValue;

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) 
    {    
        columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:columns[i]];

        if (values[i])
        columnValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:values[i]];
        else
        columnValue = @"";

        NSLog(@"%@:%@", columnName, columnValue);
    }

    return SQLITE_OK;
}

- (void)loadDataFromDatabase
{
    NSString *file = [self getWritableDBPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file]; 

    // If its not a local copy set it to the bundle copy
    if(!success) {
        //file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:DATABASE_TITLE ofType:@"db"];
        [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    }

    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

   //QUERY WORKING
     //sqlite3_exec(database, "select * from mytable", loadCallback, valueArray, NULL);

 //QUERY NOT WORKING
     sqlite3_exec(database, "select * from mytable Where company like 'SONY'", loadCallback, valueArray, NULL);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could describe what `mytable` looks like? And is the query not returning anything, or are you getting an error message?

Comment: could you post the output of **"SELECT * FROM mytable"**?

Comment: Apart from the above comments, which you should provide. If you are not looking to use wildcard, **LIKE** is a horrible way to go. user **=** instead. Save you much of the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you perhaps be looking for a SELECT statement that's more like this: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE company LIKE '%SONY%'`?